# kinesis video streams webrtc 403 forbidden on presigned websocket wss url

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket, pre-signed-url, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm using `SigV4RequestSigner` to presign a WebSocket url in aws lambda, using [Amazon Kinesis Video Streams WebRTC SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js)

In the client when attempting to call `new SignalingClient()` with a requestSigner that returns the presigned url from the server I'm getting the following error:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

What could be the reason?

Could this be a CORS issue?

Maybe the url is missing a token or a header?

Answer (score 3):

Solved when adding the `kinesisvideo:ConnectAsMaster` permission to the lambda function which signs the url.